# How to refer to the local filesystem where spark-submit is executed on?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is it possible to write output of spark program's result in driver node when it is processed in cluster?

```
df = sqlContext("hdfs://....")
result = df.groupby('abc','cde').count()
result.write.save("hdfs:...resultfile.parquet", format="parquet")  # this works fine

result = result.collect()

with open("<my drivernode local directory>//textfile") as myfile:
    myfile.write(result)    # I'll convert to python object before writing
```

Could someone give some idea how to refer to the local filesystem where I gave `spark-submit`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use `.` (the dot) and the current working directory is resolved by API.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question, you are asking about saving local files in driver or workers while running spark.

This is possible and is quite straightforward.

The point is that in the end, the driver and workers are running python so you can use python "open", "with", "write" and so on.

To do this in the workers you'll need to run "foreach" or "map" on your rdd and then save locally (This can be tricky, as you may have more than one partition on each executor).

Saving from the driver is even easier, after you collected the data you have a regular python object and you can save it in any stranded pythonic way.

***BUT***

When you save any local file, may it be on worker or driver, that file is created inside the **container** that the worker or driver are running in. Once the execution is over those containers are **deleted** and you would not be able to access any local data stored in them.

The way to solve this is to move those local files to somewhere also while the container is still alive. You can do this with a shell command, inserting into data base and so on.

For example, I use this technique to insert results of calculations into MySQL without the need to do collect. I save results locally on workers as part of a "map" operation and then upload them using MySQL "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE".